# Oracle query - Last Date multiple Items

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have some troubles with a query. The query is made for getting Article Nr. and Modification Date. Afterwards we generate a Report. It worked very well until now.

For every Product there will be 4 Stages with four Dates.
Unfortunately in the DB sometimes more than 4 Stages. In some cases the Product pass the Process twice. this means 8 Stages with 8 dates.
what i try to get:

- a list with some products
- the newest stages (youngest Date)
- Ignore, if exits the oldest Production Steps

this is my Code, (i create pseudo Code)

I tried to mix the Artikel number with the date (`concat()`).
To get an unique String.
But it is not working very well (high processing time).

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      /* Some Calculations & Cases and Critera */
    FROM
      ( 
        SELECT
          /* Get the Product Columns */
          ArtNumber,
          modDate,
          weight 
        FROM  
          /* four different Tables */  
        WHERE  
          /* Criterialist to get the Products */  
          modDate>sysdate -360  
          /* what i think, that can solve the Problem */  
        AND CONCAT(ArtNumber, modDate) IN  
          (  
             SELECT DISTINCT  
               ArtNumber  
             FROM  
             WHERE  
               (  
                 stateentrytime  >sysdate - 13  
              AND stateentrytime<sysdate - 5  
              )  
              (  
                SELECT  
                  MAX(modTime) AS highestDate,  
                  ArtNumber,  
                  CONCAT (ArtNumber, modTime) AS ArtMod  
                FROM  
                WHERE  
                  /* Criterialist to get the Products */  
                AND ArtNumber IN  
                  (  
                    SELECT  
                      ArtNumber  
                    FROM  
                    WHERE  
                      modTime>sysdate -360  
                    GROUP BY  
                      h.ArtNumber  
                  )  
                GROUP BY  
                  h.ArtNumber,  
                  CONCAT (ArtNumber, modTime)  
              )  
          )  
      )  
      ftd ,  
    WHERE  
      /* Criterialist to get the Products */  
  )  
WHERE  
  /* more Criteria */
```

Do you have some hints for me?
for

1. getting the modDate
2. optimize the query

What i expect:

```
ArtNumber | modTime
--------- | -------
12345     | 23.08.2016
12346     | 20.07.2016
12347     | 23.05.2016
12348     | 23.03.2016
```

- one Date for one Item

What i get:

```
ArtNumber | modTime
--------- | -------
12345     | 23.08.2016
12346     | 20.07.2016
12345     | 23.05.2016
12346     | 23.03.2016
```

- same Item Number
- with different Date

The Problem is, when i try to get the MAX. I get only the Item with the hightest Date back.

many thanks Phil

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your query is not remotely readable.  Can you please fix the formatting?

Comment: There are four stages per item, you say. (I imagine something like planned -> ordered -> in stock -> sold out, or something along those lines.) But all you want to show per product is the date of the last stage entered? You don't even want to see *which* stage it is in? Isn't this simply `select artnumber, max(stateentrytime) from ... where ... group by artnumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to aggregate data. You are looking for the `MAX(modtime)` *per* `artnumber`. This translates to `MAX(modtime) ... GROUP BY artnumber`. (Without the `GROUP BY` you'd get just one row aggregating *all* recods.)

Hence:

```
select artnumber, max(modtime) as modtime
from ...
where ...
group by artnumber
order by artnumber;
```